# Map appears on Shapelets data app, but none of the points are appearing

Tags: python, dataframe, function, folium

I am building a data app using Python and the folium library to create a map of stores locations in Miami. The map is appearing on the app, but none of the points are showing up on the map. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
import folium 
from pandas import DataFrame 
from shapelets.apps import DataApp, FoliumChart

selector = app.selector(title="Select the Postal Code", options=['33122','33125','33126','33127','33128','33129','33130','33131','33132','33133','33134','33135','33136','33137','33138','33139','33140','33141','33142','33143','33144','33145','33146','33147','33148','33149','33150','33151','33152','33153','33155','33156','33157','33161','33162','33165','33166','33167','33168','33169','33170','33172','33173','33174','33175','33176','33177','33178','33179','33180','33181','33182','33183','33184','33185','33186','33187','33188','33189','33190','33193','33194'])

def folium_map(data: DataFrame, selector: int)-> FoliumChart :
    # Folium map
    # create a map of Miami
    l=folium.Map(location = [25.761681
    ,-80.191788], #Initiate map on Miami city
    zoom_start = 10,min_zoom = 10)
    marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(l)
    data = data[data.postalCode == selector]
    #select other than place on data frame
    not_game_place=data[data["game"] == False]
    #select place that are not gamestop
    not_game=data_game[data_game["game"] == True]
    not_game=not_game[not_game["Gamestop"] == False]
    #select gamestop on data frame
    gamestop=data_game[data_game["Gamestop"] >0]

    #plot the map with all the locations
    for place in not_game_place.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([place["latitude"], place["longitude"]], popup=(place["name"],place["address"])).add_to(marker_cluster)
    #plot the map with all the location
    for place in not_game.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([place["latitude"], place["longitude"]],icon=folium.Icon(color='green', icon='ok-sign'), popup=(place["name"],place["address"])).add_to(marker_cluster)
    #plot the map with all the location
    for place in gamestop.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([place["latitude"], place["longitude"]],icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='ok-sign'), popup=(place["name"],place["address"])).add_to(marker_cluster)

    return app.folium_chart(title= "Map of Miami's", folium=l)

# set the map of Miami
l=folium.Map(location = [25.761681
,-80.191788], #Initiate map on Miami city
zoom_start = 10,min_zoom = 10)
# create a button for the folium map
map = app.folium_chart(title= "Map of Miami's", folium=l)
#Bind the map
map.bind(folium_map,data, selector)

app.place(map)
```

When I run this code, the app loads and the map appears, but none of the store points are showing up on the map. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I will assume that you first created your data app as:

```
app = DataApp(name= ...)
```

I see what is happening here, your options for the selector is a string, whereas you try to pass the selector in the function as a int. The way the Dataapp is working you either need to pass the option as int like this

```
options=[33122,33123,...]
def folium_map(data: DataFrame, selector: int)-> FoliumChart :
```

or do the opposite

```
options=["33122","33123","..."]
def folium_map(data: DataFrame, selector: str)-> FoliumChart :
```

I also saw that you created the map twice, once in the function and after. You don't need to include it in the function, just at the end.

```
def folium_map(data: DataFrame, selector: int)-> FoliumChart :
    
    marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(l)
    data = data[data.postalCode == selector]
    #select other than place on data frame
    not_game_place=data[data["game"] == False]
    #select place that are not gamestop
    not_game=data_game[data_game["game"] == True]
    not_game=not_game[not_game["Gamestop"] == False]
    #select gamestop on data frame
    gamestop=data_game[data_game["Gamestop"] >0]

    #plot the map with all the locations
    for place in not_game_place.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([place["latitude"], place["longitude"]], popup=(place["name"],place["address"])).add_to(marker_cluster)
    #plot the map with all the location
    for place in not_game.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([place["latitude"], place["longitude"]],icon=folium.Icon(color='green', icon='ok-sign'), popup=(place["name"],place["address"])).add_to(marker_cluster)
    #plot the map with all the location
    for place in gamestop.iterrows():
        folium.Marker([place["latitude"], place["longitude"]],icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='ok-sign'), popup=(place["name"],place["address"])).add_to(marker_cluster)

    return app.folium_chart(title= "Map of Miami's", folium=l)

# set the map of Miami
l=folium.Map(location = [25.761681
,-80.191788], #Initiate map on Miami city
zoom_start = 10,min_zoom = 10)
# create a button for the folium map
map = app.folium_chart(title= "Map of Miami's", folium=l)
#Bind the map
map.bind(folium_map,data, selector)

app.place(map)
```

you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo